# What happen to the counter value if I do not input the statement (if previous state!=current state)

Tags: arduino-uno

I refer to the code from this page: http://www.toddholoubek.com/classes/pcomp/?page_id=58 :

```
int ledPin = 13; // choose the pin for the LED
int switchPin =2; // choose the input pin (for a pushbutton)
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status
int counter = 0;
int currentState = 0;
int previousState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT); // declare pushbutton as input
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(switchPin); // read input value
  if (val == HIGH) { // check if the input is HIGH (button released)
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn LED on
    currentState = 1;
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED off
    currentState = 0;
  }
  if(currentState != previousState) {
    if(currentState == 1) {
      counter = counter + 1;
      Serial.println(counter);
    }
  }
  previousState = currentState;
  delay(250);
}
```

I do not have the Arduino device so couldn't test the result currently but am Interested to know if I omitted this line:

```
if(currentState != previousState)
```

, using the command line

```
if(currentState == 1) {
counter = counter + 1;
```

only and lets say I using a FS-V21 fiber optic sensor to count the quantity of products of 1m long each and on a conveyer belt of speed 0.1m/s so the stat will be true of t=1/0.1=10second for each product.

Will the counter value increase one unit only for each product (happen on the transition edge only), or increase indefinitely in the 10 second duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the line

```cpp
delay(250);
```

towards the end of the `loop()` function it will count up once every quarter of a second all the time the "state" is 1.

That means over a 10 second period it will count 40 objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will increment *as long as* there is a product and at the frequency your loop runs at. So, when the light is interrupted, it will count several objects within a second.

The line you want to ommit is very essential, it makes the sketch only detect edges rather than levels.